# Не могу понять почему выражение y >> x++ * z всегда равно 0

Tags: java

Делаю дз на курсах и не могу понять почему компилятор пишет что Result of 'y >> x++ * z' is always '0'. В консоли итоговый ответ 5. Подскажите пожалуйста почему же выражение равно нулю.

```java
int x = 5, y = 10, z = 15;
x += y >> x++ * z;
System.out.println("Переменная х = " + x);
```

Comment: Вы уже прочитали, что делает `>>`?

Comment: @Igor да, но у меня почему-то получилось 15 >> 75, я неправильно посчитала?

Comment: @katerina += - это операция присваивания с инкрементом, она выполняется последней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала смотрим на приоритет операторов в Java

1. Постфиксный инкремент и декремент
2. Префиксный инкремент и декремент
3. Умножение, деление, нахождение остатка
4. Сложение, вычитание
5. И самое последнее - присвоение.

Теперь расставим скобки в вашем выражении

```java
x += (y >> ((x++) * z));
```

Теперь распишем значение каждой скобки исходя из

```java
int x = 5, y = 10, z = 15;
```

1. x++ == 5,
2. 5 * 15 == 75
3. 10 >> 75 == 0
4. 5 += 0 == 5

Comment: спасибо большое за такой полный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Я не понимаю, что это значит `15 >> 75` из комментария. Число `10` (`1010`) сдвигается на `5` позиций вправо. Все единицы исчезнут, останется ноль.

Comment: да, я не в том порядке выполнила операции, поэтому и не получалось, спасибо!

Comment: @katerina А-а-а, теперь и я догадался откуда взялось `75`. Но откуда взялось `15` мне все равно непонятно.

Comment: я оператор += выполнила раньше чем нужно, сначала сложила x и y и получила 15, а потом только логический сдвиг вправо начала выполнять, поэтому и не получалось.